# I'm trying to navigate using the bottom bar but I get an error saying (Fix Bottom Overflowed By infinity Pixels) And then the whole app crashes

Tags: flutter, dart

I've tried to change the child from column to other types but still it didn't work. I'm not sure what's causing the error here but I'm suspecting it's the screens [_currentindex] placement. Also when I click on one of  the items in the bottom bar. The background color (dark blue) doesn't change to the color of my desired page. But current content disappears.

```
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<focalPointProfile> {
    int _currentIndex = 0;

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final List<Widget> screens = [
            dashboardScreen(),
            focalPointProfile(),
            mentorRegistrationScreen(),   ];

    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      endDrawer: drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
         actions: [
            Builder(
              builder: (context) => IconButton(
                    icon: Icon((Icons.settings), color: Colors.green,),
                    onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
                    tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
                  ),
            ),
          ],
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        elevation: 1,
      ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[800],
        body: SafeArea(
         minimum: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: Column( 
            children: <Widget>[              
                  Text(
                name,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                position,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey[200],
                    letterSpacing: 2.5,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro"),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
                width: 200,
                child: Divider(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),

              // we will be creating a new widget name info card

              buildTextField(email, Icons.web),
              screens[_currentIndex],
            ],
          ),
        ),
        
        bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
          height: 50,
          selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
          onDestinationSelected: (index) => setState(() => _currentIndex = index),
          destinations: const [
            NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'home'),
            NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'profile'),
            NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.add), label: 'Add Mentor'),

          ],
          ),
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<***focalPointProfile***>
> cant be the same as here

```
**final List<Widget> screens = [
    dashboardScreen(),
```

***focalPointProfile(),***

```
     mentorRegistrationScreen(),   ];
```

You can read it here.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).